# Find pairs of side integers for a given hypothenuse number so it is Pythagorean Triple

Tags: algorithms, pythagorean-triples

I am trying to find all pairs of side integers (a, b) for a given hypothenuse number n so
that (a, b, n) is a Pythagorean triple, i.e.,$ a^2 + b^2 = n^2$

The approach i am using is

1. Sorting the array in ascending order
2. Finding the square of each element in array

for(j->0 to (a.length-1))
  for (i->j+1 to  (a.length-1))
    search the a[j]+a[i] ahead in the array from i+1 to the end of array
      if found get the triplet according to sqrt(a[j]),sqrt(a[i]) & sqrt(a[j]+a[o])
  end
end

Is this approach correct?

Comment: If the hypotenuse number $n$ is given, why not just search using $a$ from $0$ to $n$ and $b$ from $a$ to $n$ [assuming pairs are to have $a \le b$]  then see if $a^2+b^2=n^2$ and so avoid squareroots. Also it's not clear what "the array" is that you refer to in your described approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all let us keep the traditional $a\lt b\lt c$ as three sides of right angle triangle and $(a+b)\gt c$ (c ,being the hypothenuse)

> ie., (a+b)=(c+d)

$ a = k(m^2 -n^2)$

b = k(2mn)

$ c = k(m^2 +n^2)$

$ d = k[{2n(m-n)}^2]$ for $m\gt n$ and interestingly

the sum of squares of two consecutive natural numbers generate the primes of hypothenuse numbers and hence say 
 m=n+1 then ' c ' will become

$  *0 c = k[ 2(n^2) + 2n + 1 ]$

$  * (c-1)/2 = k{n(n+1)}$

With given 'c' now you can find out a & b easily.

Answer (score 0):

We can find sides $A$ and $B$ given a side $C$ provided that the triple is primitive, twice a primitive, or a perfect square times a primitive and we begin by factoring $C$ for $n$. Then we look for values of $m$ that yield and integer for $n$ in a finite range determined by heuristics and logic.

$C= m^2+n^2\implies\space n=\sqrt{C-m^2}$ where $\biggl\lceil\sqrt{\frac{C}{2}}\space\space\biggr\rceil \le m\le\bigl\lfloor\sqrt{C}\bigr\rfloor$

For example, if $C=1105,\space m_{min}=\bigl\lceil\sqrt{\frac{1105}2{}}\space\bigr\rceil= 24, m_{max}=\bigl\lfloor\sqrt{1105}\bigr\rfloor=33$

Testing values of $m$ we find $\sqrt{1105-24^2}=23\rightarrow f(24,23)=(47,1104,1105)\quad \quad \quad \sqrt{1105-25^2}\notin\mathbb{N}\quad \sqrt{1105-26^2}\notin\mathbb{N}\quad \sqrt{1105-27^2}\notin\mathbb{N}\quad \sqrt{1105-28^2}\notin\mathbb{N}\quad \sqrt{1105-29^2}\notin\mathbb{N}\quad \sqrt{1105-30^2}\notin\mathbb{N}\quad \sqrt{1105-31^2}=12\rightarrow f(31,12)=(817,744,1105)\quad \sqrt{1105-32^2}=9\rightarrow f(32,9)=(943,576,1105)\quad \sqrt{1105-33^2}=4\rightarrow f(33,4)=(1073,264,1105)$

All of the above are primitve but it works for doubles and perfect square multiples of primitives. For example $10\rightarrow f(3,1)=(8,6,10)=2(4,3,5),\quad 20\rightarrow f(4,2)=(12,16,20)=4(3,4,5),\quad 45\rightarrow f(6,3)=(27,36,45)=9(3,4,5)$

But $51$ yields nothing because $(45,24,51)=3(15,8,17)$ and $3$ is neither $2$ nor a perfect square. The only way to find such triples (if they exist) is to try all of the factors, here, $17\rightarrow f(4,1)=15,8,17)$